# GDB Missing separate debuginfos Fedora 22

Tags: linux, gdb, fedora

I'm trying to debug a 32-bit ELF with GDB on Fedora 22, but I keep getting the following message:

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.21-5.fc22.i686
```

I did exacty that -- I ran:

```
sudo dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.21-5.fc22.i686
```

I get that all dependencies are resolved and that there's nothing to do. Namely, this message:

```
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:00:06 ago on Sun Sep 13 00:36:35 2015.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

But even then, when I try running the same file in gdb, I get the exact same warning message. How do I satisfy the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I satisfy the warning?

First, unless you need to debug glibc itself, you don't *have to* satisfy the warning, you can ignore it.

Second, your problem is likely caused by something in your `.gdbinit`, such as setting `debug-file-directory` incorrectly. Try starting GDB with `gdb -nx ...`. If that fixes the warning, that would prove your `.gdbinit` is the cause.